# Need help integrating trained RNN model into guess function of another code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

The [dataset](https://github.com/the-swanky-shinigami/Hangman/blob/main/RandomWords.txt) is a list of about 250,000 random words of random lengths.
Here is the code I used for training the RNN model:

```py
# Load dataset
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/words_250000_train.txt", "r") as file:
    dataset = file.read().splitlines()

# Function to prepare data
def prepare_data(dataset):
    # Preprocess dataset
    vocab = set()
    max_sequence_length = 0
    for word in dataset:
        word = word.lower()  # Convert to lowercase
        vocab.update(set(word))
        max_sequence_length = max(max_sequence_length, len(word))
    vocab_size = len(vocab)
    char_to_index = {char: index for index, char in enumerate(sorted(vocab))}
    index_to_char = {index: char for char, index in char_to_index.items()}

    # Generate sequences
    X, y = [], []
    for word in dataset:
        word = word.lower()  # Convert to lowercase
        X_word, y_word = [], []
        for char in word:
            X_word.append(char_to_index[char])
            y_word.append(char_to_index[char])
        X.append(X_word)
        y.append(y_word)

    # Pad sequences to the maximum sequence length
    X_padded = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post')
    y_padded = pad_sequences(y, maxlen=max_sequence_length, padding='post')

    return X_padded, y_padded, vocab_size, max_sequence_length, char_to_index, index_to_char

# Prepare data
X_train, y_train, vocab_size, max_sequence_length, char_to_index, index_to_char = prepare_data(dataset)


# Define model architecture
embedding_dim = 50
model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length),
    LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True),
    Dense(units=vocab_size, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train model
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 10
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_split=0.2)

# Save the model
model.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/Trained Model/Model 2")
```

Here is the code of a hangman type game where I am trying to implement the model:

```py
class HangmanOffline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.full_dictionary = self.build_dictionary("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/words_250000_train.txt")
        self.guessed_letters = []
        self.full_dictionary_common_letter_sorted = collections.Counter("".join(self.full_dictionary)).most_common()
        self.current_dictionary = []
        self.model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/Trained Model/Model 2")
        self.char_to_index = {}
        self.index_to_char = {}
        self.build_index_maps()

    model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/Trained Model/Model 2"
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

    def build_index_maps(self):
        vocab = set("".join(self.full_dictionary))
        self.char_to_index = {char: index for index, char in enumerate(sorted(vocab))}
        self.index_to_char = {index: char for char, index in self.char_to_index.items()}

    def preprocess_word(self, word):
        return [self.char_to_index[char] if char in self.char_to_index else -1 for char in word]



    def predict_next_letter(self, word):
        model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/HangmanTest/Trained Model/Model 2"
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
        encoded_word = self.preprocess_word(word)
        padded_word = np.pad(encoded_word, (0, 29 - len(encoded_word)), mode='constant')
        padded_word = np.array([padded_word])  # Add batch dimension
        next_letter_index = np.argmax(model.predict(padded_word), axis=-1)
        return self.index_to_char[next_letter_index[0]]


    def guess(self, word):
        clean_word = word.replace("_", ".")
        len_word = len(clean_word)
        current_dictionary = self.current_dictionary
        new_dictionary = []

        for dict_word in current_dictionary:
            if len(dict_word) != len_word:
                continue
            if re.match(clean_word, dict_word):
                new_dictionary.append(dict_word)

        self.current_dictionary = new_dictionary

        guess_letter = self.predict_next_letter(word)
        return guess_letter

    # The rest of the class remains unchanged...
    def build_dictionary(self, dictionary_file_location):
        with open(dictionary_file_location, "r") as text_file:
            full_dictionary = text_file.read().splitlines()
        return full_dictionary

    def start_game(self, verbose=True):
        self.guessed_letters = []
        self.current_dictionary = self.full_dictionary

        word = random.choice(self.full_dictionary)
        hidden_word = '-' * len(word)
        tries_remains = 6  # Adjusted to match the online version

        game_id = ''.join(random.choices('0123456789abcdef', k=12))  # Generate a random game ID

        if verbose:
            print(f"Successfully start a new game! Game ID: {game_id}. # of tries remaining: {tries_remains}. Word: {hidden_word}.")

        while tries_remains > 0:
            guess_letter = self.guess(hidden_word)

            if guess_letter is None:
                # No possible guess. Fall back to original logic.
                guess_letter = self.original_guess()

            self.guessed_letters.append(guess_letter)

            if verbose:
                print(f"Guessing letter: {guess_letter}")

            if guess_letter in word:
                new_hidden_word = ''
                for i, letter in enumerate(word):
                    if letter == guess_letter:
                        new_hidden_word += letter
                    else:
                        new_hidden_word += hidden_word[i]

                if new_hidden_word == word:
                    if verbose:
                        print(f"Word: {new_hidden_word}")
                        print(f"Congratulations! You won!")
                    return True

                hidden_word = new_hidden_word
                if verbose:
                    print(f"Word: {hidden_word}")

            else:
                tries_remains -= 1
                if verbose:
                    print(f"Wrong attempt! Word: {hidden_word} Tries remaining: {tries_remains}")
                if tries_remains == 0:
                    if verbose:
                        print(f"Failed game: {game_id}. Because of: # of tries exceeded!")
                    return False

# Play the game a certain number of times
total_recorded_runs = 10
total_recorded_successes = 0

hangman_game = HangmanOffline()

for i in range(total_recorded_runs):
    print('Playing', i+1, 'th game')
    if hangman_game.start_game(verbose=True):
        total_recorded_successes += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Calculate success rate
success_rate = (total_recorded_successes / total_recorded_runs) * 100
print(f'Total recorded successes = {total_recorded_successes}')
print(f'Overall success rate: {success_rate} %')
```

The problem I am facing is that whatever value I assign to blanks appearing in the first step of every game, the model tries to input it and gives an error like this:

```
indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 26)
     [[{{node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_93797]
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You are calling load_model multiple times is there a reason for it? You could just load it during object construction and reuse it?

Comment: Anyway it looks that you are giving -1 as an input to the embedding layer which accepts only integers (up to 25 in your case). The error seems informative in this sense?

Comment: @Thomas I used load model multiple times as some methods were not able to access the model idk why. And yes, I know -1 is not being accepted, I want help with that only. How to work around that. I cannot assign values between 0-25 as they are already mapped to the alphabets.